# Android studio, trying to inflate an xml file with a base xml and ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, layout-inflater

I'm trying to fill an xml (of a chat log) with an xml file of how it looks, and a class where i can get the text of the message from.

Im using ArrayAdapter and inflation. I have 2 XML files, one of them is "messageother", which is for someone elses message, and "messageme" for messages the user himself wrote.

```java
public class MsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Msg> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Msg> msgList;


    private TextView tvText;

    public MsgAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Msg> messages) {
        super(context, R.layout.activ, messages);
        this.context=context;
        this.msgList=messages;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messageother, parent, false);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Now, this would just duplicate the same xml file of "messageother" until its done.
Instead, id like to go one by one in the ListView, and check if the Msg.getMine() = true;
If so, id like to inflate that one with the xml "messageme" like so:

```java
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messageme, parent, false);
```

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class MsgAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Msg> {
    private static final class ViewHolders {
        View mMessageOthersView;
        View mMessageMeView;
        private ViewHolders(@NonNull final LayoutInflater layoutInflater, @NonNull View parent) {
            this.mMessageOthersView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.messageother, parent, false);
            this.mMessageMeView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.messageme, parent, false);
        }
    }

    private final ArrayList<Msg> msgList;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public MsgAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Msg> messages) {
        super(context, R.layout.activ, messages);
        this.msgList = messages;
        this.mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolders cViewHolders;
        if (convertView == null) {
            cViewHolders = new ViewHolders(this.mLayoutInflater, parent);
            convertView.setTag(cViewHolders);
        } else {
            cViewHolders = (ViewHolders)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final View finalView;
        final Msg cMsg = this.getItem(position);
        if (cMsg.getMine()) finalView = cViewHolders.mMessageMeView;
        else finalView = cViewHolders.mMessageOthersView;

            //"finalView" is the final inflated Layout
        finalView.findViewById(....)

        return finalView;
    }
}
```

A further step could be Caching all needed View for each of Layouts avoiding to do a complete "findById()" for each Item......